# Finding a numeric ID within an URL including numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, url, str-replace

I've run into some problems accessing and forwarding an ID.
I successfully extracted the ID from my URL but I run into problems if the URL contains unpredictable numbers aswell.

To clear things up a bit:

*My efforts to extract the ID so far (JS)*

```
var idString = window.location.href;
    idString = idString.replace(/e107/gi, "__ersetzt__");
    idString = idString.replace("http://localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/", "");
    idString = idString.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
```

Some URL examples

Working:

*http://localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/BMW/235_Projekt_BMW-Event/page.php*    Result: 235 = id

Not working:

*localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/BMW/235_Projekt_BMW-Event01/page.php*

*localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/company1337/235_Projekt_1337Event/page.php*

now if I could exclude the   /******_Projekt_    Part (**** = random amount of numbers) and parse it into an Integer I would be fine, but I dont know how to do this or if it's possible.

I tried to find something on here and via google but I most likely dont ask for the right stuff.

*Thanks for your time and help in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/BMW/235_Projekt_BMW-Event/page.php';
var id = +url.match(/\/(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Incredible. 

Thanks for such a fast answer! 

I dont really understand how this extraction works but it does.

If you dont mind, I would love an explaining how this particular url.match works.

Comment: @Detale You're welome - remember to mark the correct answer with the thick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Is this URL you are working on stable in terms of structure?
If you are nto familiar with Regular Expressions and the Structure is pretty stable , then the following code will do the job for you:

```js
var myString = "http://localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/BMW/235_Projekt_BMW-Event/page.php";
var mySplitString = myString.split("/");
var myNumber = parseInt(mySplitString[8]);

console.log(myNumber);
```

Adding the below Function which will provide you with a bit more flexibility.

```js
var myString = "http://localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/BMW/235_Projekt_BMW-Event/page.php";

function getProject(myString , myDist){
  var mySplitString = myString.split("/");
  var myID = '';
  mySplitString.forEach(function(key , index){
    if(key.indexOf(myDist) > 0)
     myID = parseInt(mySplitString[index]);
  });

  return myID;
}

var myID = getProject(myString , "Projekt");
console.log(myID);
```

Comment: **http://localhost/Westbomke/backendV5/e107-master/e107_projekte/** is the normal structure used in all links concerning those pages. after that is the **company name** which changes alot, followed by the **unique ID**. **\_Projekt\_** is constant too and **BMW-Event** is the project Name which changes aswell. **page.php** is constant again.   I really appreciate your effort to help me. I'll use hsz's code for now, if I run into any problems and it wont work for some reason (switch from localhost to online for example) I am going to try your solution.